# scala - String split("|") works incorrectly?

Tags: scala

I've encountered a strange question on scala String split

here is my code:

```
scala> val s1 = "oauth_token=FOO&oauth_token_secret=BAR&oauth_expires_in=3600"
s1: String = oauth_token=FOO&oauth_token_secret=BAR&oauth_expires_in=3600

scala> s1.split("&")
res3: Array[String] = Array(oauth_token=FOO, oauth_token_secret=BAR, oauth_expires_in=3600)
```

so far, the `split` method works well, but..

```
scala> val s2 = "oauth_token=FOO|oauth_token_secret=BAR|oauth_expires_in=3600"
s2: String = oauth_token=FOO|oauth_token_secret=BAR|oauth_expires_in=3600

scala> s2.split("|")
res4: Array[String] = Array("", o, a, u, t, h, _, t, o, k, e, n, =, F, O, O, |, o, a, u, t, h, _, t, o, k, e, n, _, s, e, c, r, e, t, =, B, A, R, |, o, a, u, t, h, _, e, x, p, i, r, e, s, _, i, n, =, 3, 6, 0, 0)
```

the method actually splits out every character, even strangely, an empty string appears at the front.

I have tried other delimiters such as `%`, `,`, the method still works well. It seems that `split` does not work correctly when `|` serve as delimiter?

Answer (score 12):

`split()` expects a regular expression, and in [regex-land](http://www.regular-expressions.info) `|` means "OR", so you're splitting on the empty string OR on the empty string, which is what you're seeing.

You can use an escape to split on literal `|`s:

```
scala> val s2 = "oauth_token=FOO|oauth_token_secret=BAR|oauth_expires_in=3600"
s2: String = oauth_token=FOO|oauth_token_secret=BAR|oauth_expires_in=3600

scala> s2.split("\\|")
res0: Array[String] = Array(oauth_token=FOO, oauth_token_secret=BAR, oauth_expires_in=3600)
```

Answer (score 5):

Scala has an implicit conversion which provides `split()` method on strings that accepts `char`:

```
scala> val s2 = "oauth_token=FOO|oauth_token_secret=BAR|oauth_expires_in=3600"
s2: String = oauth_token=FOO|oauth_token_secret=BAR|oauth_expires_in=3600

scala> s2.split('|')
res0: Array[String] = Array(oauth_token=FOO, oauth_token_secret=BAR, oauth_expires_in=3600)
```

Naturally, this only works if your splitter is a single character. If it is a multi-character string, you need to keep track of regex-specific characters yourself.